# Is there a cost to learning new rites?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

My character currently has 5 dots in the Rites background. This gives them 5 levels of rites, which they have already selected. Now they want to learn a new rite. What does it cost?

Does it cost...

- Nothing. They already have Rites maxed out, so there is no mechanical barrier to learning more.
- Nothing. The highest level of Rites is already achieved. It isn't possible to learn more rites.
- XP. I didn't see this in print, but it seems sensible. I just don't know how to adjudicate it.
- Something else entirely.

I'm using the 1e rules, but am open to suggestions from other versions. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45213/what-is-the-experience-cost-of-learning-a-ritual) covers V:TM. How about Werewolf? I didn't see similar language in my book.

Comment: wow, 1st edition is so unstructured and gappy at times. Things one remembers from 2nd/revised had not yet been in rule explanations then! I think the Player's guide is to blame...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Rites cost no XP

In no edition's XP spreadsheet there is any line for indicating XP costs for rites. It is never even mentioned that learning rites costs XP. <sup>1, 3, 5, 7</sup>

There is a roll and time spent with the teacher, that's it. <sup>2, 4, 6, 8</sup>

On the contrary, later generations have the outspoken rule that only at character generation one can obtain rites with background or freebie points, in 1st edition that is only implicit. <sup>4, 6, 8</sup>

> Subsequently [to character generation], however, rites can be learned only through roleplaying; they may not be purchased with experience points.
> <sup>6</sup>

## The teacher of a rite may want compensation

However, the rules for any but the first edition indicate, that one should sway the prospective teacher of the rite and repay him for their time. This repayment is at times described to be possible to be done by doing services to the teacher, but it sees usual to provide them with talens or other items. <sup>4, 6, 8</sup>

#### References

1. W:tA core rule book, 1st Edition (1991), p. 168 - Experience Chart
2. W:tA core rule book, 1st Edition (1991), p. 188 - Learning a Rite
3. W:tA core rule book, 2nd Edition (1994), p. 188 - Experience chart
4. W:tA core rule book, 2nd Edition (1994), p. 138 - Learning Rites
5. W:tA core rule book, revised Edition (2000), p. 182 - Experience chart
6. W:tA core rule book, revised Edition (2000), p. 155 - Learning a Rite
7. W:tA core rule book, 20th Anniversary Edition (2012), p. 244 - Experience chart
8. W:tA core rule book, 20th Anniversary Edition (2012), p. 201 - Learning a rite